# Vectorisation of "if not:" statements in loops

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization

I'm attempting to improve my current code as it is not efficient. Currently I'm using iterrrows() to loop through a DataFrame, and I'm doing this for every file, resulting in a time consuming program.

The for loop looks at each row in the DataFrame (there's only 2 columns), and if value in the column '3' is not found in another DataFrame it skips the value, otherwise it does a few simple calculations.

Below is the code I'm looking to improve upon. It is returning two lists (BP_Shear and BP_Dis) which are then plotted.

```
BP_Shear = []
BP_Dis = []
for index, Total_row in Total_Data.iterrows():
    if not IT_Data[IT_Data['3'] == Total_row['3']].empty:
        BP_Shear.append(Total_row['3'])

        row_number = IT_Data[IT_Data['3'] == Total_row['3']].index

        BP_Dis.append(Total_row['2'] - mean(IT_Data.iloc[row_number]["2"]))
```

I've tried list comprehension - which actually added 20 seconds to the code. I'm currently trying to get vectorisation to work but am having no luck.

Edit: Some sample data, excuse the formatting, and further explanation.

Essentially, for each row in Total_Data (called Total_row in the code), I first check column '3' exists in IT_Data, if it doesn't exist we skip to the next line. If it does then the Total_row['3'] is appended to BP_Shear, and we get all row numbers where Total_row['3'] matches in IT_Data['3'] and then subtract the mean of these values from Total_row['2'] and append the result to BP_Dis.

| IT_Data |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 3 |
| 26 | 0.128 | 0.01 |
| 27 | 0.128 | 0.01 |
| 28 | 0.128 | 0.01 |
| 29 | 0.127 | 0.00 |
| 30 | 0.128 | 0.00 |
| 31 | 0.131 | 0.01 |
| 32 | 0.130 | 0.01 |
| 33 | 0.130 | 0.01 |
| 34 | 0.132 | 0.01 |
| 35 | 0.135 | 0.01 |
| 36 | 0.134 | 0.01 |
| 37 | 0.134 | 0.01 |
| 38 | 0.135 | 0.02 |
| 39 | 0.138 | 0.02 |

| Total_Data |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 3 |
| 26 | 0.198 | 0.01 |
| 27 | 0.198 | 0.01 |
| 28 | 0.201 | 0.01 |
| 29 | 0.202 | 0.02 |
| 30 | 0.201 | 0.02 |
| 31 | 0.201 | 0.02 |
| 32 | 0.205 | 0.02 |
| 33 | 0.205 | 0.02 |
| 34 | 0.207 | 0.02 |
| 35 | 0.207 | 0.02 |
| 36 | 0.205 | 0.02 |
| 37 | 0.207 | 0.03 |
| 38 | 0.210 | 0.03 |
| 39 | 0.209 | 0.03 |

Comment: if you are really concerned about performance and your data is big enough for you to feel the impact of your approach the best solution that comes to mind right now is to convert your data input format to CSV and parse it line by line
it takes about 0.010 seconds to proccess 15000 lines of data in a cheap PC

Comment: All the data is currently in CSV format and being read into the program with pd.read_csv. The program is only taking a few minutes to run at the moment, but I expect it'll take a lot longer once I get all the data. And this section looks the easiest part to improve upon.

Comment: If you provide some example data so we can run your code that would make it easier to understand.

Comment: See edit - I've included some sample data and further explanation. I hope that helps, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Thanks. Note that with the data provided you need to change the code `mean(IT_Data.iloc[row_number]["2"]))` to `mean(IT_Data.loc[row_number]["2"]))`.  Also, would you mind showing where `mean` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
matches = Total_Data['3'].isin(IT_Data['3'])
BP_Shear = Total_Data.loc[matches, '3']
IT_means = IT_Data.groupby('3').mean()
BP_Dis = Total_Data.loc[matches, '2'] - IT_means.loc[BP_Shear, '2'].values

print(BP_Shear)
print(BP_Dis)
```

Output:

```
26    0.01
27    0.01
28    0.01
29    0.02
30    0.02
31    0.02
32    0.02
33    0.02
34    0.02
35    0.02
36    0.02
Name: 3, dtype: float64
26    0.0670
27    0.0670
28    0.0700
29    0.0655
30    0.0645
31    0.0645
32    0.0685
33    0.0685
34    0.0705
35    0.0705
36    0.0685
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It's about 5 times faster on this small dataset.  On bigger ones, it should be a lot faster I think.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a treat - made the significantly faster (~5x on the bigger data set too). I'm still new to python obviously, but it's amazing out of the 120+ lines of code, a change to those few can make such a big difference.

Comment: A follow up question for a potential improvement - currently I use the mean of matches as a work around as I couldn't get it to work when subtracting due to duplicates.  For example, in the data above, when '3' match at 0.02, you get 0.202 - 0.135, and then the next row it would be 0.201 - 0.135 instead of 0.201 - 0.138. The cycle would never go to the next IT_Data match. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Generally, try to avoid asking following up questions in the comments of an existing question.  Post a new one.  But it sounds like you're trying to compute a rolling average or cumulative average.  Google how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can skip the `itterows()` step and just merge the two tables.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Total_Data = pd.DataFrame({'3':np.random.randint(0,20,10)}) # dummy data
IT_Data = pd.DataFrame({'3': np.linspace(0,5,6)})
data_needed = Total_Data.reset_index().merge(IT_Data, on = '3')
```

The column `index` would give you the `row_number` as per your old code. After that, you can do the calculations that are required.

Comment: That's close - it looks like it is merging Total_Data and IT_Data where they match in '3', the issue is I want it to keep '3' from Total_Data where it matches, but perform a calculation from IT_Data where it matches. See the edits, hopefully that makes sense.